# function to return a variable of type of another class

Tags: java

I need a function to take a name and return the details of the record associated with that name.How do i do this? I have all the info. in my result set, but i need a way to pass it to one variable and return the value in java. I am using eclipse-juno under CentOS

Comment: Tried any thing on `Eclipse-Juno under CentOS`? If you have it, utilize it. Else uninstall.

Comment: how do you identify the record using that name?

Comment: What have you tried? Your question is way too vague to answer at the moment... it's unclear what the real problem is.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a `Person` class with fields `Name`,`Address` and `Age` and I am assuming you want to find all the details of a `Person` given his/her `Name`, you can write a method that returns an object of `Person` class like this:

```
//Assuming Person class is declared with all fields and/or appropriate setters-getters.
//create a method to get all the details of a particular person based on name.
public Person getPerson(String name){
   //get all the details from the database in a resultset rs
   //Create a new object Person class
   Person p = new Person();
   //set the details from the resultset to this newly created Person object
   p.setName(rs.getString("name");
   p.setAddress(rs.getString("address");
   p.setAge(rs.getInt("age");

   //now your Person object is ready with all the details that you need, you return it to callinh method

  return p;

}
```

You can use this returned `Person` object using getters to access the fields.

Comment: Thanks all for the reply.I had the same idea as Abu suggested, but was looking if any other better method existed.Thank you.